# Getting reference of Startup.cs object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here's the skeleton of a standard ASP.NET Core application:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
    .Build();

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

In this piece the ASP.NET Core apparatus instantiates an instance of `Startup.cs` class

```
.UseStartup<Startup>()
```

My query is how can I get hold (reference) of this already instantiated instance of Startup object that I can plug into my Library/Framework.

Context is to setup some Uber level framework and get a reference of this junction (Startup.cs) where all the requests are getting initiated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your `Startup` implements `IStartup` interface, getting reference to it is easy:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseConfiguration(config)
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();

var startup = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IStartup)); // or from any other part of code using IServiceProvider.
```

However, asp.net core does not *require* your startup class to implement this interface. If it does not - it will use adapter pattern and adapt your `Startup` class to `IStartup` interface. You will still have an instance of `IStartup`, but it will not be your `Startup` class. Instead it will be an instance of `ConventionBasedStartup`. Asp.net core will explore methods of your startup class, find `Configure` and `ConfigureServices` methods and will pass them to `ConventionBasedStartup` which will adapt them to `IStartup` interface. In this case, it's not possible to retrieve instance of your startup class without heavy reflection, because it's not actually stored in any field (even in private) of `ConventionBasedStartup` and is only reachable through delegate references.

Long story short - if you want to get instance of your `Startup` class - make it implement `IStartup` interface.

Update about how to implement IStartup interface:

```
public class Startup : IStartup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // constructor as usual
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {            
        app.UseMvc();
        // resolve services from container
        var env = (IHostingEnvironment) app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IHostingEnvironment));
        var logger = (ILoggerFactory)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(ILoggerFactory));
        logger.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logger.AddDebug();
        // etc
    }        

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddMvc();
        // etc
        // return provider
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems promising, I've added `IStartup` as an interface to the `Startup` class, it's complaining for `ConfigureServices` return type, question is what should I return within `ConfigureServices` to match requirements of `IStartup` interface, I'm new to .net.

Comment: Thanks, visual studio code is complaining for few dependencies, for instance `ConfigurationBuilder` and `IConfigurationRoot`. I have created a basic bare bone simplest web app using generator `yo aspnet`. Want a simplest implementation at `Startup.cs` level since heavy lifting will be done in my framework. Also I don't want to plug into `mvc` of `asp.net mvc` since I've my own custom implementation. At the very simplest level I want the Startup object just to `delegate` the incoming requests to my framework.

Comment: Note that my example just shows how to implement IStartup interface. IConfigurationRoot, Startup constructor, UseMvc etc are provided just as placeholders to show you how you can do that. It is in no way necessary. Just implement Configure and ConfigureServices with provided signatures however you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive reply... got it. I'm testing,

Comment: almost there, it works fine, using new method `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app), the old overloaded method with `IHostingEnvironment` and `ILoggerFactory` params are not in use and that's fine except that I might need to know hosting environment in my uber framework, is there a way to retrieve it there?

Comment: Just read my example once again, I show there how to retrieve IHostingEnvironment and ILoggerFactory in Configure method, exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate.

Comment: Hi, can you please also look into this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062316/intercepting-and-delegating-requests-to-a-custom-object-library

Comment: I tried this solution, but it cause a new Startup instance to be created. Any suggestion(s)?